# Can open jupyter notebook in browser but cannot open in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I always use jupyter notebook in my chrome notebook, and I find I can use vscode to achieve open jupyter and want to try it.
So I use the anaconda in my WIN10 system to create a jupyter notebook, and I check it's okay to open in my browser.
Then I use this command in my vscode

```
ctrl+shift+P
```

and then click the line "jupyter: specify the jupyter server for connection". Then put the jupyter link with token into the "Existing" and enter, but nothing happens even without a error.

More information:

1. I install the jupyter extensions in my vscode, like the "Jupyter","Jupyter keymap" and "Jupyter notebook renderers"
2. I can use SSH link to my remote linux server and open the remote .ipynb files in my vscode then I can edit and run code.

I am using: anaconda 3 vs code 1.66.2 windows 10. Please help, and let me know if any more information is required.

Sorry for no pictures as I have not enough reputation. I upload a video in Youtube (https://youtu.be/p_TYceK9dkI).
I guess Jupyter in vscode can not used as Jupyter in browser? (for the variables vanished when I close my vscode)

Answer (score 0):

You should install jupyter notebook extension so that you can run jupyter on vscode.
[image]

Comment: Thx, but I have installed the three extensions in my vscode, and these problems still exist. I can use SSH link to my remote linux server, and then open .ipynb file, edit and run python code. But the variables vanished after I close the SSH link. So I want to use remote jupyter in my vscode, as the jupyter notebook (or lab) used in browser.

Comment: @gedebahe You can refer to the document of vscode. I think there is no problem with vscode. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_connect-to-a-remote-jupyter-server